# WooCommerce - Query for ordered products

Tags: database, query, woocommerce-offtopic, mysql

I'm trying to obtain all orders for particular day/time and then order products using SQL (MySQL) as seen in the query below:

```
select 
    p.ID as order_id,
    p.post_date,
    i.order_item_name,
    max( CASE WHEN im.meta_key = '_product_id' and p.ID = im.order_item_id THEN im.meta_value END ) as Prod_ID
from 
    wp_posts as p,
    wp_postmeta as pm,
    wp_woocommerce_order_items as i,
    wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta as im
where 
    p.post_type = 'shop_order'
    and p.ID = pm.post_id
    and p.ID = i.order_id
    and p.post_date BETWEEN '2016-01-14 00:00:00' AND '2016-01-14 23:59:59'
    and p.post_status = 'wc-processing'
```

It looks like when I try to query `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` table for ordered products data I'm loosing connection to a database (connection timed out during a query).

Any clue what is going on?

Comment: This is kind of [off-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) since it's about MySQL *and* WooCommerce but not specifically about WordPress. Maybe you're hitting a limit and the tables are too big or something - I'm definitely not a MySQL expert but maybe `LIMIT` your results to 1 or 2 and see if anything is returned. Another idea is to `COUNT()` the number of rows it expects to return.

Comment: There are only 46 orders for that day so shouldn't be a problem. Anyway I will try to hit WooCommerce devs on WP forum then.

Comment: While you may only see 46 orders in the backend - it could be a malformed query that is returning more results than you expect which may be the core of the issue - just suggestions to rule out the little things. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed query

```
select 
        p.ID as order_id,
        p.post_date,
        i.order_item_name,
        max( CASE WHEN im.meta_key = '_product_id' and i.order_item_id = im.order_item_id THEN im.meta_value END ) as Prod_ID
    from 
        wp_posts as p,
        wp_postmeta as pm,
        wp_woocommerce_order_items as i,
        wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta as im
    where 
        p.post_type = 'shop_order'
        and p.ID = pm.post_id
        and p.ID = i.order_id
        and p.post_date BETWEEN '2016-01-14 00:00:00' AND '2016-01-14 23:59:59'
        and p.post_status = 'wc-processing'
```

Explanation: Post ID has no direct relation to the order item meta

Comment: very inefficient sql, you should join the itemmeta table instead of the cross join. should delete this answer

Comment: `In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'p.ID'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Answer (score 3):

Wanted to update this, as I found it when building out my own reporting.

A better method is to do the proper inner joins, minimizing query times:

```
select 
    p.ID as order_id,
    p.post_date,
    i.order_item_name,
    max( CASE WHEN im.meta_key = '_product_id' and i.order_item_id = im.order_item_id THEN im.meta_value END ) as Prod_ID
from 
    wp_posts as p
    inner join
    wp_postmeta as pm 
    on p.id = pm.post_id
    inner join
    wp_woocommerce_order_items as i 
    on p.id = i.order_id
    inner join 
    wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta as im 
    on i.order_item_id = im.order_item_id
where 
    p.post_type = 'shop_order'
    and p.post_date BETWEEN '2017-04-29 00:00:00' AND '2017-04-30 23:59:59'
    and p.post_status = 'wc-processing';
```